# Layout misconfiguration issue in tests on my phone

Tags: java, android-studio

My layout is completely disfigured when doing the tests on my phone, the entire interface goes to the top of the screen making testing difficult.

My computer has a low configuration and I can't emulate it, but my cell phone has a very high resolution and I don't know if that's why the layout is misconfigured.

- On my phone the interface would look like this, but it doesn't.

[image]

- Code layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".RegisterPerson">
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editName_people"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter the person's name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="94dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmail_person"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter the person's email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="155dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTelephone_person"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="enter the person's telephone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="213dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_insert_person"
            android:layout_width="161dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:background="#397939"
            android:text="Register person"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="49dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="298dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_list_persons"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:background="#171688"
            android:text="List person"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="238dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="298dp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Person data"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="100dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Would it be better a ```LinearLayout```?

Comment: ConstraintLayout is usually a good approach to create layouts. The advantages of ConstraintLayout become more obvious with more complex layouts. For simple use cases, a LinearLayout can of course also be applied (or RelativeLayout etc). This is individual and depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ConstraintLayout`, I would recommend you to use constraints. For example, you can position the first `EditText` at the top of the `ConstraintLayout` and the other `EditText` below it.

For example:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName_people"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter the person's name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail_person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter the person's email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editName_people" />
```

---

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

positions the top of a element at the top of the wrapping `ConstraintLayout`.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editName_people"
```

positions the top of a element to the bottom of the element addressed by @id.

By using  `android:layout_marginTop` & `android:layout_marginBottom` you can add a vertical distance between the elements.

By using some of these constraints you can position the elements horizontally.

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/..."
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/..."
```

Additionally use dp values for width/height, which you save in `dimens.xml` and access it via its id.

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/tv_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tv_height"
```

Comment: All fields inside the linearlayout would not be better?